# Delete NA in a column in R

Tags: r, na

```
persnr          stterm kurs reg  prog betyg  datumklar omreg
1 411223-6213    V11 MM2001 FFG FRIST     C 2012-09-21 FALSE
2 420211-6911    V12 MM2001 FFG FRIST  <NA>       <NA> FALSE
3 420604-7716    H07 MM2001 FFG FRIST  <NA>       <NA> FALSE
4 430404-8558    H11 MM2001 FFG FRIST     B 2012-01-11 FALSE
5 431030-7030    H08 MM2001 FFG NMFIK  <NA>       <NA> FALSE
6 440127-0055    H13 MM2001 FFG FRIST     B 2014-06-12 FALSE
```

I would like to set all `NA` values under `datumklar` to 0. 
and the same for `betyg`. How could I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? R functions can deal with `NA` values easily whereas a 0 might lead to wrong results.

Comment: +1 billion to @Roland's comment. Also why are you replacing `<NA>` in columns which appear to be _date_ and _character_ based on your example data with 0? That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your `data.frame` is called `df`, you can then do this:

```
df$betyg[is.na(df$betyg)] <- 0
df$datumklar[is.na(df$datumklar)] <- 0
```

You are basically telling R "please substitute `NA` value with zero in each case.